# How to plot just one axis label in R?

Tags: r, plot

A beginner question: I currently have some plots that look like this.

[image: plot with no labels]

I'm keeping the plots free of other annotation because I have to fit a lot of them onto one page and specific values aren't important, just the general trend that the red line is to the right of the black one. However, I'd like to be able to indicate that the dashed line in my plot actually represents zero, like so:

[image: plot with zero on x-axis]

Is there any way to tell R to *only* display that value on the x-axis labels? I don't think using `text()` would be a good idea because it relies on absolute coordinates, but I'm not really sure how to work with `axis` options to make it do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
axis(side = 1, at = 0)
```

See `?axis` for details.

Comment: That worked brilliantly! Clearly I need to get better at reading the documentation ;-)